# Need to to capture feedback(text) on click of a Like & Dislike button in Communities

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, aura

Has anyone developed an aura cmp to capture feedback on click of a like & dislike Button. I found an appexchange package for this but it needs tweeks to fulfil my requirements, Unfortunately the package is managed so I can't edit the code for it. I try to use flows but It cant be used on community page. So I'm left with the option of creating my owm cmp.

If anyone has done the same functionality but on a different context it will be very helpful and time saving. Any leads are appreciated..[image]
I used a lightning card to display this text and buttons, Need help in showing a text box when user clicks like button.

Comment: Hi! It would be easier to help if you shared your code with us.

Comment: One suggestion is to try it through Vlocity, using an omniscript.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Caroline, I got it worked using a simple cmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```html
<template>        
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label='Yes' onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>  

    <template if:true={isVisible}>    
        <lightning-input type="text" label="Enter some text"></lightning-input>
    </template>
</template>
```

JS:

```js
@track isVisible = false;  
      
handleClick(event) {  
    this.isVisible = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks azul, I created a AURA cmp with same functionality, It works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: With this code, I need to enter vote record through APEX, but the issue is VOTE is a standard object and cannot be customized as per developer guide. Any ideas as to how we can utilize this VOTE functionality, I'm thinking maybe I can create a custom object to store feedback and have a lookup to VOTE to link the feedback description. Any Ideas's?

Comment: yes, you could create a custom object to store the feedback, vote type (positive/negative) and article id, then use this id to insert/update a vote record

Answer (score 1):

```
<aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.renderCard}">   
    <lightning:card iconName="utility:unmuted" title="Was this article helpful ?">
        <aura:set attribute="actions">
            <div class="slds-grid">
                <lightning:button label="Yes" iconName="utility:smiley_and_people" onclick="{!c.clickedLike}" iconPosition="left" />
                <lightning:button label="No" iconName="utility:sentiment_neutral" onclick="{!c.clickedDisLike}"/>
            </div>
        </aura:set>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:renderIf>
<aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.renderTextbox}">
    <lightning:textarea name="likeInput" label="{!v.respondText}" placeholder="type here..." />
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit article feedback" title="Brand action" onclick="{! c.saveFeedback }" />
</aura:renderIf>
<aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.renderThanks}">
    <p><lightning:formattedText value="Thanks for your feedback." /></p>
</aura:renderIf>
```

Controller.JS

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper){
        var action = component.get('c.isrendered');
        action.setCallback(this,function(result){
            component.set('v.renderCard',result.getReturnValue());
            console.log(result.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    
    clickedLike : function(component, event, helper){
        console.log('Clicked Like button...');
        component.set("v.renderCard", false);
        component.set('v.renderTextbox', true);
        component.set('v.respondText',"Great to hear");
    },
    
    saveFeedback: function(component, event, helper){
        console.log('clicked on save feedback button...');
        component.set('v.renderTextbox', false);
        component.set('v.renderThanks', true);
    }
})
```

Comment: I've posted my answer, Hope it will help others who are looking for similar thing. It still needs an APEX class and small tweeks as per your requirements.

Comment: Thanks @moonpie for ur suggestion to combine the answer in one post.